# How to decrypt AES-encrypted files with Data Connection?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

I'm looking for the best way to ingest AES-encrypted `.csv` files in Foundry. What would be the quickest way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box support for symmetric decryption. However, ingested files can be processed downstream in Transforms using cryptography libraries in Python or Spark.